# I keep getting error after I added UISearchController in tableview

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchcontroller

I keep getting this message fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) 
on this line(marked with */ */)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
       */ if resultSearchController.active */
        {
            return self.filtered.count
        }
        else
        {
            return self.entries.count
        }

    }
```

The table view is loaded from coreData

```
class NotesListTableViewController: UITableViewController ,UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext!
    var entries: [NSManagedObject]!

    var filtered :[NSManagedObject] = []
    var resultSearchController:UISearchController!
```

entries is used to load from coredata and filtered is the used to store data after searching

can anybody please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that resultSearchController is nil.

You can either, change the ! on the property to a ?, then the compiler will force you to handle the case where it might be nil whenever you try to access it. Or, you can review why it is nil and fix that. For example, are you never creating it in the first place?